# Somar variáveis no javascript

Tags: javascript

Olá! Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.buttonAdd').click (function(){
    $(this).closest('.row').find('.inputQtd').val();
    var iqtd = $(this).closest('.divAddProdutosPagamentos').find('.inputQtd');
    var qtd = Number(iqtd.val());
    iqtd.val(qtd+1);
    var badgeCount = badgeCount + qtd+1;
    $('#badgeCarrinho').text(badgeCount);
  });
});
```

Basicamente, toda vez que o usuario clicar no '.buttonAdd' irá somar mais um.
O sistema é um carrinho de mercado, portanto há varios produtos no carrinho.
A minha variavel 'badgeCount' deve exibir o total de itens no carrinho, ou seja, se voce adicionou 2 arroz e 2 feijoes, minha variavel badgeCount deve exibir 4.
No java é facil, faço badgeCount += qtd. Pois irá armazenar o total. Mas no javascript nao estou conseguido fazer isso.
Alguem poderia me ajudar? A imagem serve para melhorar a explicação: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como pode ver, tenho 3 itens no meu carrinho, e gostaria que minha variavel badgeCount armazenasse o total desses 3 itens (no caso 6).

(A variavel badgeControl é exibida no canto superior direito, ao lado do icone do carrinho)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta percorrer cada input de quantidade com `.each()` e somar os valores. Veja que a variável `badgeCount` inicia do `0`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.buttonAdd').click (function(){
      var iqtd = $(this).closest('.divAddProdutosPagamentos').find('.inputQtd');
      var qtd = Number(iqtd.val());
      iqtd.val(qtd+1);

      var badgeCount = 0;

      $(".inputQtd").each(function(){
         badgeCount += Number($(this).val());
      });

      $('#badgeCarrinho').text(badgeCount);
   });
});
```

Comment: Funcionou!!!! Obrigado!